# Type error trying to call Any() using Expression<Func<..>> from method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I am creating a reusable mapping expression from my EF entity to my BLL entity:

```
private Expression<Func<Person, bool>> GetNameFilter(string name)
{
    return person => person.Profile.UserName == name;
}

internal Expression<Func<Ef.Perk, Bll.Perk>> MapPerkPerk(string name)
{
    return perk => new Bll.Perk
        {
            Id = perk.PerkId,
            Name = perk.PerkName,
            Description = perk.PerkDescription,

            //Compilation Error
            Owned = perk.Players.Any(GetNameFilter(name)) 
        };
}
```

And I am getting a compilation error on the noted line. The error reads:

> ICollection does not contain a definition for 'Any' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Any(IQueryable, Expression>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

But this does not happen when I push this expression in directly:

```
internal Expression<Func<Ef.Perk, Bll.Perk>> MapPerkPerk(string name)
{
    return perk => new Bll.Perk
        {
            Id = perk.PerkId,
            Name = perk.PerkName,
            Description = perk.PerkDescription,

            //No Compilation Error
            Owned = perk.Players.Any(person => person.Profile.UserName == name)
        };
}
```

Why is this happening? The type of both expressions is the same.

Using the LinqExpression solution found below, I am now getting the following error at runtime:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in LinqKit.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

```
internal FutureQuery<Perk> GetPlayerInfoPerks(string username)
{
    return Master
            .Perks
            .VisiblePerks
            .Select(Master.Perks.MapPerkPerk(username))
            .Future();
}
```

Is this due to the use of the EntityFramework.Future library?

Comment: Are you using `using System.Linq;`in your class?

Comment: Is it allowed to use 3rd party packages?

Comment: I am using System.Linq. I would prefer not to use 3rd party, but I'm not opposed to them if it allows me to follow DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening? The type of both expressions is the same.

The **type** of both expressions is **not** the same - they just look visually the same. The following is valid:

```
dbContext.Persons.Any(GetNameFilter(name))
```

and this is not:

```
perk.Players.Any(GetNameFilter(name))
```

Why? Because the first expects `Expression<Func<...>>` while the second - just `Func<..>` (the typical difference between `IQueryable<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` methods with the same name). Hope you see the difference. When you type it directly, the C# compiler does its magic to emit one or the another, but when you do that manually, you are supposed to use the correct one.

The problem is addressed by [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) package with `Invoke` / `Expand` custom extension methods (and more generally with `AsExpandable`).

For your concrete example, the LinqKit solution could be like this:

```
using LinqKit;

...

internal Expression<Func<Ef.Perk, Bll.Perk>> MapPerkPerk(string name)
{
    // LinqKit requires expressions to be in variables
    var nameFilter = GetNameFilter(name);
    return Linq.Expr((Ef.Perk perk) => new Bll.Perk
    {
        Id = perk.PerkId,
        Name = perk.PerkName,
        Description = perk.PerkDescription,
        Owned = perk.Players.Any(p => nameFilter.Invoke(p)) 
    }).Expand();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to work with a simple Func<Person, bool>? That compiles fine, but it throws a 1025 runtime error.

Comment: I am also getting an error with this setup, I will edit the OP to specify this case.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't have exactly what you had written, thanks for this fix!